# Doxygen FULL_PATH_NAMES does not generate full paths in file names

Tags: unique, doxygen

I have two libraries libA and libB.

libA contains a file Action.h
libB contains a file action.h

I want to generate doxygen documentation in the same output directory for both libraries. This directory is to be used in Windows, for which action.html and Action.html is unfortunately considered to be the same file. To prevent this clash, I wish to render the generated files unique by prepending their path names to them.

Therefore, I set FULL_PATH_NAMES to YES.

I expect to see something like libA_Action.html and libB_action.html when I generate the documentation, but I don't! I still see Action.html and action.html. Its as if the FULL_PATH_NAMES parameter does nothing at all. Do I also need to set some other parameter in the Doxyfile to make the FULL_PATH_NAMES parameter work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running doxygen twice - one time for each library. If that is the case, doxygen isn't aware of the fact that it might clash with an output from another run, so when it find an existing file, it assumes that it is leftover from a previous run, and overrides it.

Setting FULL_PATH_NAMES doesn't help, as doxygen has no idea that multiple libraries exist, so, as far as doxygen is concerned, the prefix is identical to all files, so even when you adding a force it, it adds nothing (That's probably a bug).

The solution to your problem is setting both libraries as inputs to the same doxygen project.
You can do it by setting INPUT to multiple folders in the configuration file:

```
INPUT                  = ...bla\Lib1 \
                         ...bla\Lib2
```